# Error en Function PHP

Tags: php, php7

Recientemente he actualizado mi version de MySQL de la 5.7 a la 8 y me he encontrado con el siguiente error en una de mis funciones PHP

```
function contar_nueva_recarga_a_sp(){
global $db, $usua, $contador_recarga_a_sp_badge;

    $id_usuario = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $web = "recargas_a_sin_plan.php";

    $cont_visita = "SELECT * FROM visitas
                    WHERE fecha_visita =  (
                        SELECT MAX(fecha_visita)
                        FROM visitas WHERE web = '$web' AND id_usuario = '$id_usuario')  ";
    $result_visita = mysqli_query($db, $cont_visita);
    $row_visita =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_visita);

    $fecha_visita = $row_visita['fecha_visita'];
// 2019-07-06 12:38:35
    $cont_msn = "SELECT * FROM pedidos
                WHERE usuario = '$usua' AND operador = 'A' AND sin_plan = '1'
                AND fecha_entrega > '$fecha_visita'";

    $resultcont = mysqli_query($db, $cont_msn);
    $rowcont =  mysqli_num_rows($resultcont);

  if ($rowcont == 0){
    $contador_recarga_a_sp_badge = "";
   }
   else if ($rowcont < 2) {
    $contador_recarga_a_sp_badge = $rowcont;
  }
  else if ($rowcont > 1) {
    $contador_recarga_a_sp_badge = $rowcont;
  }


}
```

Antes no me daba error pero ahora me da un error de `:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`  en la linea donde se declara la variable `$rowcont =  mysqli_num_rows($resultcont);` temporalmente he solucionado declarando la variable con un @ al principio `@$rowcont =  mysqli_num_rows($resultcont);` pero no logro visualizar el error ya que en otra funcion tengo un codigo exactamente igual y no muestra errores.

Se que el error en cuando la sentencia `$cont_msn`  no tiene datos o en su defecto cuando esa sentencia SQL esta vacia.

Comment: ¿Revisaste `mysqli_error($db)`? antes de `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Comment: Fijate que el error que me da es `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in` en la evaluacion de la variable cuando esta es nula

Comment: En primer lugar, no es buena idea silenciar los errores con `@`. Tu tarea como programador no es ignorar los errores, sino afrontarlos. Deberías entonces controlar el código, por ejemplo verificando que la primera consulta trae datos antes de lanzar la segunda, cosa que no haces y que es el núcleo del problema aquí. Por otra parte, podrías crear una sola consulta para obtener lo que quieres, uniendo ambas tablas mediante un `INNER JOIN`